# If Cell Matches Cell in Either Column Return Adjacent Cell Text

Tags: excel, vlookup

So I have an excel spreadsheet that is supposed to keep track of grades, but I can't seem to get conversion from letter grades to numerical grades right. I'm trying to match cells from I21:I48 against reference letter grades in G10:G15 and I10:I15, and then replace G21:G48 with the corresponding numerical grades.

Here are the conversion cells arranged in two rows for nice formatting, one of the reasons it's hard:

```
      <G>   <H>   <I>   <J>
<10>   A    4.0    C    2.0
<11>   A-   3.7    C-   1.7
<12>   B+   3.3    D    1.0
<13>   B    3.0    F    0.0
<14>   B-   2.7    NA   0.0
<15>   C+   2.3    I    0.0
```

Here are some example data cells, with [FILL] on the cells to fill in:

```
        <G>       <H>           <I>   
<20>   GRADE     TERM      Letter Grade
<21>   [FILL]   Term 3           A
<22>   [FILL]   Term 3           A-
<23>   [FILL]   Term 3           A
<24>   [FILL]   Term 3           A
<25>   [FILL]   Term 3           A
<26>   [FILL]   Term 3           C
<27>   [FILL]   Term 2           B
<28>   [FILL]   Term 2           A
...
<48>   [FILL]   Term 1           A
```

Here is what that same chart should look like filled in, using the letter grades column to match against the conversion chart above:

```
        <G>       <H>           <I>   
<20>   GRADE     TERM      Letter Grade
<21>    4.0     Term 3           A
<22>    3.7     Term 3           A-
<23>    4.0     Term 3           A
<24>    4.0     Term 3           A
<25>    4.0     Term 3           A
<26>    2.0     Term 3           C
<27>    3.0     Term 2           B
<28>    4.0     Term 2           A
...
<48>    4.0     Term 1           A
```

Comment: its not very clear what youre after. mind breaking it down a bit more?

Comment: Two VLOOKUP()'s (one for each column), using IFERROR() to return blank when no match

Comment: @DougCoats The first table above is a conversion chart, letter grades to numerical grades, where A goes to 4.0, B+ goes to 3.7, etc. Using that table, replace each element in the 'Grade' column of the second table with the numerical grade corresponding to the entry in the 'Letter Grade' column, yielding the third table

Answer (score 0):

`=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I21,$G$10:$H$15,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(I21,$I$10:$J$15,2,FALSE)),"???")`

Pasting that in G21 and filling it down should do the trick.

This would have been a bit easier and required less nesting if your table was fully sequential, instead of having it split across four columns as opposed to two. I have a second IFERROR to show `???` just incase the item in column I isn't actually in the table and needs manually investigated.

Answer (score 0):

You are fighting a poorly organized table.  In **G16** enter:

```
=I10
```

copy this cell across one column and then down:

[image]

Now you can do a simple *VLOOKUP()* on `G10:H21`

Comment: As mentioned in the question, reorganizing the table for simplicity's sake isn't an option

Answer (score 0):

This works but it isnt a worksheet solution. Basically loops through each letter grade in a predefined column and spits the answer out where you tell it to.

```
Private Sub gradeconversion()
Dim rNg As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim vAr As Double
Set rNg = ActiveSheet.Range("i1:i100")
For Each rCell In rNg.Cells
    If rCell.Value <> vbNullString Or rCell.Value <> "" Then
        Select Case rCell
            Case Is = "A"
                vAr = 4
            Case Is = "A-"
                vAr = 3.7
            Case Is = "B+"
                vAr = 3.3
            Case Is = "B"
                vAr = 3
            Case Is = "B-"
                vAr = 2.7
            Case Is = "C+"
                vAr = 2.3
            Case Is = "C"
                vAr = 2
            Case Is = "C-"
                vAr = 1.7
            Case Is = "D"
                vAr = 1
            Case Else
                vAr = 0
        End Select
        rCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = vAr
    End If
Next rCell

End Sub
```

its not the prettiest code but it works for what you need.